# CSharpScript memory leaks in ASP.NET core APi

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an asp core api.
A route can execute several c# scripts from database to get some calcul results on the same context/globals.

So I have this code:

```
    public static async Task<FormulaEvalException> TryEvalAsync<T>(this T formulaContext) where T : FormulaContext
    {
        FormulaEvalException res = null;
        ScriptState state = null;
        var scriptOptions = ScriptOptions.Default.WithReferences("System", "System.Linq", "System.Globalization", "Microsoft.CSharp").WithImports(new[] { "System", "System.Linq", "System.Math", "System.Globalization", "System.Collections.Generic" });
        foreach (var formulaList in formulaContext.AllFormulas.Values)
        {
            foreach (var formula in formulaList)
            {
                formulaContext.CurrentFormula = formula;
                try
                {
                    if (state == null)
                    {
                        state = await CSharpScript.RunAsync(formula.Script, scriptOptions, formulaContext);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state = await state.ContinueWithAsync(formula.Script);
                    }
                    var result = state.ReturnValue;
                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        if (res == null)
                        {
                            res = new FormulaEvalException(formula.Title + " : No result");
                        }
                        continue;
                    }

                    formula.Result = result;
                }
                catch (CompilationErrorException ex)
                {
                    if (res == null)
                    {
                        res = new FormulaEvalException(formula.Title + ex.Message);
                    }
                    continue;
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

This code leads me to memory leaks and the user cannot repeat these requests.

From my previous searches, I got some informations as my formulaContext class as to located in another project. So I put it in a model project outside my API project. But I still have this issue.

I tried several way to execute my script (with CSharpScript.Create or CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync for example) but the memory is still not released.

I also heard about AppDomain class to execute my script in sandbox and release memory after using but AppDomain is not used anymore in ASP.NET Core.

Thank you for help ;)

Comment: That's how .NET works. Once an type or assembly is loaded, it can't be unloaded anymore. In the past one did solve it by creating a new AppDomain and loading the assembly there, so you could unload the AppDomain w/o unloading the main application. But this isn't possible anymore. You will either have to do it with separate processes (probably too slow for your use case) or you will have make sure that one formula is only complied once and then cached to execute the already compiled code at a later point. This of course only works when your formulas have no internal state, may require rewrite

Comment: Thank you for your reply Tseng !!!

I was thinking using Azure Storage to record compilation of formulas/scripts and executing them later from storage. Is that possible ?

Comment: Not sure. If I remember correctly I read somewhere that its not possible to save on the fly generated CIL code to a file right now in, but it may be wrong .NET Core. But its enough if you complie it in your application and keep the reference somewhere (along with an expiration time, so that it allows you to use newer versions of it from the database (you may have to use different namespace for each version or version the type itself) without having to restart the application

Comment: When I will use script.Compile(), it won't load the assembly yet ? 
How to do this ?

Comment: I'm trying to compile the code with CodeDom, save it on storage, and call it from my method. Is that a good way ?

Comment: @thibaudlosc use a profiler to find what's actually going on, don't assume the cuplrit is `CSharpScript`. Calling `String.Split` 1M times will create *at least* 1M temporary strings that need to be garbage-collected at some point

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a fix :

```
                finally
                {
                    GC.Collect();
                }
```

The memory fall from more than 1 GB to 250 MG. I know, once an type or assembly is loaded, it can't be unloaded anymore but the formulas are very small so I suppose my memory was full because of the CSharpScript's compilation process.

I'm waiting now for the ability to unload assemblies to definitevely clean that.
Apparently, it is planned : https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/552

Thank Tseng for your help.

Comment: That's not a fix. This means *your code leaks* temporary objects. It doesn't matter how small the formula is if you create the same one 1M times. Use a profiler to find *which* objects eat up memory. In Visual Studio you can use the Diagnostics Window to take memory snapshots at different points and compare them to find new objects, which objects take a lot of memory. It could be that the problem is cause by `String.Split` after all

Comment: As said above, you should almost never-ever have to call the GC manually. If you are, it's a sign that something seriously is wrong.
Try to use the memory profiler inside Visual Studio whilst stepping, check the events such as collections etc. 
You'll come closer to the code that is causing a leak

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I' m checking now and let you know

Comment: I have removed GC.Collect() in order to test.
For the first formula, I got 5108 KB more for an addition of 12036 objects.

Comment: In object number, the most added is the 913 syntaxt Token added for 36KB.
The most memory usage is the 99 KG of SortedInt32KeyNode<ImmutableDictionary+HashBucket<String, String>>. Maybe that come from my globals variable (which contains dictionnary).

Comment: For the other formulas, I get 61 KB by new formulas in average.The most memory usage is 14 Hashtables for 89 KB. I got also 122 more Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AssemblyIdentity for 34 KB.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you guys tripping out so much. Unloading of Assemblies/Types is NOT supported in DotNet Core and is not going to be until 3.0.

I am working on a CMS/VFS for DotNet Core and this is the single biggest obstacle at the moment.